# How can I make a screenshot of iPhone desktop programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to make a screenshot of the iphone desktop and set it as background for my app, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIGetScreenImage should do what you want - check out [this example](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html).
But apparently, Apple (in its great wisdom) has [banned its usage in apps for the App Store](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/07/21/devsugar-rip-uigetscreenimage/), and has removed it from iOS 7 arm64 and newer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to take a screenshot then you need to press the menu button and the lock button at the same time, as for setting it as the background of the app, just use the image which will automatically be placed in your camera roll.